# Count number of occurrences using Python

Tags: python

I have a list in python that looks like this:

```
data = ['12,34,212,90,1,8','901,2,1,8,44,1,1','77,32,11,230,894','78,23,45,89,12,20']
```

How do I count the number of occurrences for each number?

Output should be something like...

```
12:x
34:x
212:x
```

Where x is the number of times the value is found in the whole list

I've tried the following but not working as intended.

```
d = {}
#[ d.update( {i:d.get(i, 0)+1} ) for i in data ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)  You will have to flatten the list first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Comment: You do realize that your data is a list of strings?

Comment: you need to split your strings and convert them and then this question is an obvious duplicate as has been linked above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = ['12,34,212,90,1,8', '901,2,1,8,44,1,1', '77,32,11,230,894',
        '78,23,45,89,12,20']

d = {}
for item in data:
    for i in item.split(','):
        d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
        
for i, j in d.items():
    print(f'{i}:{j}')
```

explanation : You first iterate over the `data` list, then you split the strings to get the numbers, then `d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1` will do the counting. finally  I iterated over the result dictionary and prints the output you want with f-string.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the original list to a list of strings where the original strings are split.

```
data = ['12,34,212,90,1,8','901,2,1,8,44,1,1','77,32,11,230,894','78,23,45,89,12,20']
t = []
{t.extend(e.split(',')) for e in data}
print(t)
```

The resulting list would look like this:

```
['12', '34', '212', '90', '1', '8', '901', '2', '1', '8', '44', '1', '1', '77', '32', '11', '230', '894', '78', '23', '45', '89', '12', '20']
```

Then you simply use the `count()` method of the list. For instance:

```
t.count('1')
```

Will give you:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the list of string into a list containing just the values.

```py
res = []
for i in data:
    res += i.split(',')
```

---

Then we can use python's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to count each value:

```py
from collections import Counter

res = []
data = ['12,34,212,90,1,8','901,2,1,8,44,1,1','77,32,11,230,894','78,23,45,89,12,20']

for i in data:
    res += i.split(',')

res = Counter(res)
for key in res:
    print(f"{key} exist {res[key]} times")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7PasMwDIfP01OIXpIwUfLHpUkgpz1GyaG0DhNN7GBr0FL67Jk8Vl2k7xM/W@tDvr1rtm0KfsGLn2d7EfYuIi@rD4Jf/seJDQDBRhzwNML1LOc0ZVVNjaFaW1dSRW1GWVdWVKeZjNFWqToeqVGlvimp7UxSrQKZgyJpui6zEWDyARnZYXq/B9RKX34OyPu4ziy5Jov3Hf9n5UrFX/RmHyms3AN8rIGd5NPuqfqF9s5R8Km7k/L4QuHFxl0B2/YL)

---

Output:

```
12 exist 2 times
34 exist 1 times
212 exist 1 times
90 exist 1 times
1 exist 4 times
8 exist 2 times
901 exist 1 times
2 exist 1 times
44 exist 1 times
77 exist 1 times
32 exist 1 times
11 exist 1 times
230 exist 1 times
894 exist 1 times
78 exist 1 times
23 exist 1 times
45 exist 1 times
89 exist 1 times
20 exist 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

using `Counter` and `join`

```
# your code goes here
data = ['12,34,212,90,1,8','901,2,1,8,44,1,1','77,32,11,230,894','78,23,45,89,12,20']
from collections import Counter
result = Counter(map(int, ','.join(data).split(',')))
print(result)

# output

# Counter({1: 4, 12: 2, 8: 2, 34: 1, 212: 1, 90: 1, 901: 1, 2: 1, 44: 1, 77: 1, 32: 1, 11: 1, 230: 1, 894: 1, 78: 1, 23: 1, 45: 1, 89: 1, 20: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down in two steps.

**1. Retrieve the numbers**

You have a list of strings and each string has numbers separated by commas that need to be parsed.

```py
>>> numbers = [int(x) for s in data for x in s.split(',')]
>>> numbers
[12, 34, 212, 90, 1, 8, 901, 2, 1, 8, 44, 1, 1, 77, 32, 11, 230, 894, 78, 23, 45, 89, 12, 20]
```

tip: the correct order of the `for` statements when flatting in a comprehension is the same as if you would iterate using two nested `for`s.

**2. Count!**

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(numbers)
Counter({1: 4, 12: 2, 8: 2, 34: 1, 212: 1, 90: 1, 901: 1, 2: 1, 44: 1, 77: 1, 32: 1, 11: 1, 230: 1, 894: 1, 78: 1, 23: 1, 45: 1, 89: 1, 20: 1})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
d = dict()
for i in data:
    temp = i.split(",")
    for num in temp:
        n = int(num)
        if n not in d: 
            d[n] = 1
        else: 
            d[n] += 1
```

Comment: That won't work.. for lots of reasons!

Comment: Oh shit. My bad totally didn't realise it was list of strings. Sorry

Comment: posting solution without testing or running ?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: it's better if you provide explaination